# How can 32 or 64 bit CPUs do arithmetic operation on big numbers?

Tags: encryption, cpu-architecture

Encryption and decryption with a key of 128bit means that the key can't be stored in a long int variable. So what arithmetic operations exactly can be done with this key.

Comment: You could take a look at the BN (big number) code in [OpenSSL](http://openssl.org/), for example.  There's also the GNU [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) package that could be the basis of what you're after.  Of course, 128-bit arithmetic is only a small expansion over 64-bit; those packages are capable of handling far larger computations, such as 2048 or 4096 bit numbers which might be used in Public Key Cryptography.  You might want to think of 128-bit arithmetic as similar to the way 8-bit or 16-bit or 32-bit CPUs do 16-bit or 32-bit or 64-bit arithmetic.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Your comment would have been worth an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me just ask you a question back: How do you multiply or divide if you have only your brain, a pen and paper - and the number is larger than what you can compute directly using your brain?

The same scheme you use for pen and paper mathematics can be applied for numbers that are longer than the CPU register.

For certain crypto algorithms there are also optimized and specialized mathematical operations like [Montgomery Multiplication](http://www.mersennewiki.org/index.php/Montgomery_multiplication) for RSA

Comment: And just as with calculations done 'by hand' there are a lot of optimizations that can take place. One of the first pentium ranges [famously had a bug](http://www.willamette.edu/~mjaneba/pentprob.html) in a table used for division.